# Taxation in Albania for US citizen

Tags: taxes

[Expatra](https://expatra.com/guides/albania/living-in-albania/) says that Albania taxes world-wide income at *average* of 23% (but pensions are exempt).  There is apparently no USA-Albania treaty to avoid double-taxation.  But US foreign tax rules should result in my [paying whichever country’s tax is higher](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20917/us-tax-for-expats-where-no-double-taxation-treaty-exists-vietnam).

Is there an online source in English, Spanish, Italian, or Dutch where I can determine the tax I would pay on investment income?